# Change Repeater DIV back ground

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, html

In repeater i want **this div** to change its back ground colour onclick AND When click again the colour must reset to old colour,when i try whole repeater is chowing that color. 
Appreciate your help

```
<div id='h<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>' class="header"
      onclick='ToggleDisplay(<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "ItemIndex") %>);'>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>

   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>
   <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "LicenseName")%>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way .

```
<script>
     var color = '';
     $('.header').click(function (e) {       
     var x = $(this).css('backgroundColor');    
     hexc(x);        
    if(color="red")
    {
     $(this).parent().find('.header').css('background-color', 'Your Previous Color');    
    }
    else
    {
      $(this).parent().find('.header').css('background-color', 'red');
    }    
    });

    function hexc(colorval) {
        var parts = colorval.match(/^rgb\((\d+),\s*(\d+),\s*(\d+)\)$/);
        delete(parts[0]);
        for (var i = 1; i <= 3; ++i) {
            parts[i] = parseInt(parts[i]).toString(16);
            if (parts[i].length == 1) parts[i] = '0' + parts[i];
        }
        color = '#' + parts.join('');
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Add Jquery Script library